# How to print an array verbatim Javascript

Tags: javascript

Say I have an array "x", and x shows as `[["A", "B", "C"], ["D", "E", "F"]]` in the console. How would I convert this to a string verbatim, with all the brackets and quotes?

For example, this should output
 `"[["A", "B", "C"], ["D", "E", "F"]]"`
(if possible, it would also be nice to add backslashes to the special characters, like `"\[\[\"A\", \"B\", \"C\"\], \[\"D\", \"E\", \"F\"\]\]"`)

Comment: `JSON.stringify([["A", "B", "C"], ["D", "E", "F"]])` try this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `JSON.stringify`:

```
var x = [["A", "B", "C"], ["D", "E", "F"]];
var string = JSON.stringify(x);
```

Answer (score 0):

To print it like in your console you can use `JSON.stringify()`.

```
const arr = [["A", "B", "C"], ["D", "E", "F"]];
const str = JSON.stringify(arr); // [["A","B","C"],["D","E","F"]]
```

If you also want to add a backslash to every bracket and quotation mark you could loop through every character of the string and add a backslash where it's needed.

```
// ES6 version
let escapedStr = "";
[...str].forEach(c => {
    if (c === ']' || c === '[' || c === '"') c = `\\${c}`;
    escapedStr += c;
});

console.log(escapedStr) // \[\[\"A\",\"B\",\"C\"\],\[\"D\",\"E\",\"F\"\]\]
```

If you do not want use ES6 you can do the same with a simple for loop

```
for (var i = 0, c=''; c = str.charAt(i); i++) { 
    if (c === ']' || c === '[' || c === '"') c = `\\${c}`;
    escapedStr += c;
}
```

Edit: Using Regex you can solve the problem in one line

```
const arr = [["A", "B", "C"], ["D", "E", "F"]];
JSON.stringify(arr).replace(/(\[)|(\])|(\")/g, $1 => `\\${$1}`)
```